# Avoid multiple node_modules on local development environment

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I use node and gulp to compile SASS, minify javascript, copy file, etc. However, since I have 100+ projects on my local development environment (OSX), I'm starting to wonder why I need 300 NPM packages (40MB, 7000 files!) in every single project I start. And that's when I just install gulp and gulp-sass.

Surely there is a better way to use node/gulp/sass. I have tried using GUI tools like compass and Codekit, but I like working with Gulp and I like working from the command line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check your node/npm version.  Newest version of npm flattens by default which results in much fewer modules total.  There is also an alternative called `pnpm` which can reduce module installs quite a bit by linking when existing versions match.

Comment: What exacly do you mean by 'flattens by default' ? I'm running NPM 3.10.7 and I'm stilling getting tons of modules in every single project.